# Does MariaDB Support Materialized views?

Tags: mariadb, materialized-view

Before I even try to experiment with MariaDB, could anyone tell me if MariaDB supports **Materialized views**? I can't seem to find it in their documentation.

This is one of my major issues with MySQL (the fact that it does not have materialized views out of the box). This is a major feature for me in a database, and I would like to know if MariaDB supports it.

Comment: I think no. But it has computed columns which can be persistent. See their docs: [`VIRTUAL` columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/sql-commands/data-definition/create/virtual-columns/)

Comment: Postgres supports materialized views

Comment: No, they are not supported, have a look at this other answer:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86790/best-way-to-create-materialized-view-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, no, but see Flexviews: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/documentation/clients-and-utilities/flexviews/

Note: This seems to have been [deprecated](https://github.com/greenlion/swanhart-tools) now and the link above no longer works.